# Powershell to install .\file errors, but when given full location C:\Users.... doesn't error

Tags: powershell, installation, windows-installer

I have a script below that errors when trying to access a file, however if I change the location of the .msi file in the -argumentlist to a full address it succeeds, but I can't have it run like that as the address will change when I submit it to be packaged for SCCM deployment.

```
    Function Get-OSCComputerOU
{
    $ComputerName = $env:computername
    $Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Computer)(Name=$ComputerName))"

    $DirectorySearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $DirectorySearcher.Filter = $Filter
    $SearcherPath = $DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
    $DistinguishedName = $SearcherPath.GetDirectoryEntry().DistinguishedName

    $OUName = ($DistinguishedName.Split(","))[1]
    $OUMainName = $OUName.SubString($OUName.IndexOf("=")+1)

    $OUMainName
}
$strOU = Get-OSCComputerOU
$strTrueOU=$strOU.split('_')[1]
$strCSV=Import-Csv \\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER\CSV.csv
$strRoomChannel=$strCSV | where {$_.Room -eq $strTrueOU} | % channel
IF ($strRoomChannel){
$strRoomFoundArg="/i .\Installers\MSI.msi CHANNEL=$strRoomChannel"
Start-Process msiexec -ArgumentList $strRoomFoundArg -wait
} ELSE {
msg * "Channel is missing, and can not install correctly, please call tech support on Ext: to have this rectified, it's a quick fix."
}
```

When I use a full address such as below, it installs fine.....what's the deal.

```
    Function Get-OSCComputerOU
{
    $ComputerName = $env:computername
    $Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Computer)(Name=$ComputerName))"

    $DirectorySearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $DirectorySearcher.Filter = $Filter
    $SearcherPath = $DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
    $DistinguishedName = $SearcherPath.GetDirectoryEntry().DistinguishedName

    $OUName = ($DistinguishedName.Split(","))[1]
    $OUMainName = $OUName.SubString($OUName.IndexOf("=")+1)

    $OUMainName
}
$strOU = Get-OSCComputerOU
$strTrueOU=$strOU.split('_')[1]
$strCSV=Import-Csv \\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER\CSV.csv
$strRoomChannel=$strCSV | where {$_.Room -eq $strTrueOU} | % channel
IF ($strRoomChannel){
$strRoomFoundArg="/i C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Installers\MSI.msi CHANNEL=$strRoomChannel"
Start-Process msiexec -ArgumentList $strRoomFoundArg -wait
} ELSE {
msg * "Channel is missing, and can not install correctly, please call tech support on Ext: to have this rectified, it's a quick fix."
}
```

I get this error:

[image: Error when installing with .\Installers\MSI.msi]

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is that '.' is going to be resolved by the process you are calling, msiexec, which, like most processes, is going to use the process's CurrentDirectory for '.', which is different than the current location in PowerShell. You can see the difference if you compare `Get-Location` and `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory]` in PowerShell. They will be different if you start powershell and change the directory using `Set-Location` (aka cd).

The solution is to resolve the path in PowerShell before sending it over to msiexec:

```
$path = Convert-Path .\Installers\MSI.msi
$strRoomFoundArg = "/i `"$path`" CHANNEL=$strRoomChannel"
Start-Process msiexec -ArgumentList $strRoomFoundArg -wait
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the script wasn't happy with the .\ in front of the MSI file.

If I kept the .\ I would get the error.

If I removed the .\ and just had MSI.msi then it worked fine.

I failed to mention that I had changed the active directory to my desktop to execute the script, my apologies @mike z

Thank you very much for your input however.